Proving that a Hamiltonian transformation is canonical - Condensed Matter, Altland and Simons
In the book Condensed Matter Field Theory of Altland and Simons, page 63 eq 2.30 in the second edition, they are doing the following transformation for the Hamiltonian:
$$\hat{H} \rightarrow  \hat{H'} = e^{-t\hat{O}}\hat{H}e^{t\hat{O}}.\tag{2.30}$$
They are claiming that this transformation is canonical therefore doesn't change the physics of the system. $\hat{O}$ is a general operator.
My question is why it this true? Did I missed something from their discussion?

You need to provide more context. In which section does that appear (i.e. which topic)? A quick browsing in my third edition did not show any such equation (though I may have overlooked it). Do they really say "canonic" and if yes, what do they mean/what does this mean?


A quantum canonical transformation is an adjoint group action $\hat{F}\mapsto {\rm Ad}(\hat{U})\hat{F}=\hat{U}\hat{F}\hat{U}^{-1}$ with a unitary operator $\hat{U}$, cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post.

Comparing the unitary operator $\hat{U}$ with eq. (2.30) in A&S, the operator $t\hat{O}$ should apparently be anti-selfadjoint.



A&S is probably implicitly assuming that the operator under scrutiny is an observable, and thus automatically Hermitian under general quantum postulates. Irresponsible, but not intolerable.
